# How to start the Google home screen on Android when it's not the default?

Tags: android

I have a home screen replacement app.  It is set via the GUI to always be used as the home screen.  How can I get that activity to start the original home screen on demand?  Is there a published activity name for it?  I want my replacement home screen to remain the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of activity is

> com.android.launcher.Launcher

Comment: Thanks, where can I find a list of the available ones?  Somewhere at developer.android.com?  I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Well for the launcher app it's a part of android open source project but not part of a SDK, you can check sources at http://android.git.kernel.org/. There also source for apps like Dialer,Settings and all other apps which are included in Android platform